# Can't figure out how to convert Javafx project into gluon mobile

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I apologize for having to ask such a basic question, but I have tried and looked at many different tutorials and I can't figure out how to get my existing Netbeans JavaFX program converted into a gluon one.

I tried creating a new gluon project and copying my source files in the directory but that resulted in many files not showing.
Any tutorials would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add screenshots and code snippets of what you have tried?